# Gitlab runner shell executor can't execute docker commands

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Instead of executing a docker command as a simple shell instruction, gitlab-runner tryies to connect to a docker deamon. How do I fix that?

It is gitlab-runner with the shell executor

Snippet out of .gitlab-ci.yml

```
# Test Deploy
test-job1:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - shell-testing
  only:
    - testing
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - whoami
    - pwd
    - echo "docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_TEST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG:$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_TEST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker run -d -p 8000:8000 $CI_REGISTRY_TEST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

Output of job:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.1.0 (865283c5)
  on app-testing-shell [some ID], system ID: [some other ID]
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on app-testing...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Skipping Git repository setup
Skipping Git checkout
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ whoami
gitlab-runner
$ pwd
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/[some ID]/0/root/py-helloworld-flask-docker-example
$ echo "docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_TEST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG:$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
docker pull [REGISTRY IP]:443/root-py-helloworld-flask-docker-example:12f06021fcbcddea450b91e6972ad95341d34fb8
$ docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_TEST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
Post "http://dockerservice:2375/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=[REGISTRY IP]%3A443%2Froot-py-helloworld-flask-docker-example&tag=12f06021fcbcddea450b91e6972ad95341d34fb8": dial tcp [?SOME OTHER PUBLIC IP?]:2375: i/o timeout
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

But it works fine if I execute it in the shell by myslef:

```
$ sudo su - gitlab-runner
$ whoami
gitlab-runner
$ cd /home/gitlab-runner/builds/[some ID]/0/root/py-helloworld-flask-docker-example
$ docker pull [REGISTRY IP]:443/root-py-helloworld-flask-docker-example:12f06021fcbcddea450b91e6972ad95341d34fb8
12f06021fcbcddea450b91e6972ad95341d34fb8: Pulling from root-py-helloworld-flask-docker-example
d52e4f012db1: Already exists
7dd206bea61f: Already exists
2320f9be4a9c: Already exists
6e5565e0ba8d: Already exists
d3797e13cc41: Already exists
70f90dfe001b: Already exists
bd75605de417: Already exists
3d0e1a4b14bc: Already exists
73ee9fc7cab0: Pull complete
76f48c27aa39: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4ba2eba4fc8afff2dfe4e7ad80f49aee001afb9385eb522a4898bbaacbed6617
Status: Downloaded newer image for [REGISTRY IP]:443/root-py-helloworld-flask-docker-example:12f06021fcbcddea450b91e6972ad95341d34fb8
[REGISTRY IP]:443/root-py-helloworld-flask-docker-example:12f06021fcbcddea450b91e6972ad95341d34fb8
```